# VIM Syntax coloring for error listings

Tags: vim

We use shell scripts to call various `cmake` operations to build our product.  The information echoed to STDERR is the errors output from the g++ compiler.  I can use stream redirection to get the errors into a file

```
myBuild.sh 2> errors
```

and I can edit that file along with the various sources.  Syntax highlighting is working in the .cpp's and .h's but the errors file is unhighlighted.

Is there a way to get vim to colorize my errors file?  Perhaps adding a filetype as in errors.err or some script stored in $VIM_something?

**Example output**

```
/wxyzModule/wxyzModule.h: In member function 'void WxyzModule::setIsTesting(bool)':
/wxyzModule/wxyzModule.h:48:48: error: 'm_isTesting' was not declared in this scope
```

If I :set filetype=cpp, the *48:48* is red, *bool* is green, and *not* and *this* are yellow.  Everything else stays the same white as if no highlighting were done.

Answer (score 1):

Consider instead to using `:make` from within vim, you can set it to use your shell command by setting `:h 'makeprg'` option, eg.) `set makeprg=myBuild.sh\ 2>&1`, the default `:h 'errorformat'` should work with this, otherwise you could tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

Though your error file contains C++ function and variable names, **it is not C++ syntax** (especially the overall structure with the filename in front is different). Therefore, trying to apply `:setfiletype cpp` to it is bound to fail.

If you really need highlighting in that, you have to write your own syntax plugin (e.g. called `g++errorformat`). You can certainly copy certain syntax elements from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/cpp.vim`, but essentially, you're writing a separate syntax.

Note: If you load the error file into Vim's *quickfix list* (`:cfile errors`), you'll get basic highlighting of filename and line / column, and amenities like jumping to the location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the filetype in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) to e.g. `cpp` with

```
:set filetype=cpp
```

If you want to know what `filetype` you are currently using, you can just type

```
:set filetype
```

If you don't want to type that every time, you can use an `autocmd`

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.err   set filetype=cpp
```

Comment: Querying my filetype returns **filetype=** i.e. no filetype.  Setting it to cpp highlights a few words here and there, but nohting special.  It's a file of error messages, not code, though some lines may contain  bits of code.

Comment: What kind of highlighting do you want to have? An existing one? You can also write your own syntax highlighting: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files

Comment: Good question. For now I can live with cpp colouring.  I guess I expected the "in file included from" lines to be a different color that the actual errors.  Maybe the filenames in a another different colour? ... ASIDE: Interesting, this thing wants British spellings.

Comment: What about writing a custom errorformat and using the quickfix window instead?